# Norm 1 projection in a $C^*$-algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

On a Hilbert space, it is known that projections have a norm greater than 1 (except $0$), and that those of norm 1 are exactly the orthogonal projections.
Most of the proofs I have seen use the Hilbert space, either a specific vector in it, or $\ker p$, or ${\rm im\,}P$.

I was wondering if we could prove this in a general $C^*$-algebra (when there are non trivial projections), not using an underlying Hilbert space (given by a GNS construction).

For example, the implication "orthogonal projection implies norm 1 (or 0)" works in a general $C^*$-algebra because
$$\|x\| = \|x^2\| = \|x^{*} x\| = \|x\|^2 \Rightarrow \|x\| \in \{0,1\}$$

I have not been able to prove the converse without using a Hilbert space. 
So I have a norm 1 projection $x$, I am pretty sure I need to work inside the $C^*$-algebra $C(x)$ generated by $x$ and its adjoint.

The fact that $\|x\| = \underset{y \in C(x), \|y\|=1}\sup \|xy\| = \underset{y \in C(x), \|y\|=1}\sup \|yx\|$ (attained for $y = x^*$) might be useful.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: @AndréS.: how to prove that a norm-one idempotent is selfadjoint.

Comment: It seems implied by your question that you don't want this approach, but you could take the universal representation of the $C^*$-algebra and use an argument mentioned in the first paragraph to obtain the result.

Comment: I have a question regarding the answer. How do you know that there are no negative numbers in the spectrum of $a$ ?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1210968)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have $\|x\|=1$, $x^2=x$. Write $x=a+ib$, with $a,b$ selfadjoint. The equality $x^2=x$ is now
$$
a=a^2-b^2, \ \ \ b=ab+ba.
$$
From the first equality, $a^2-a=b^2\geq0$. So $a^2\geq a$, which tells us that $\sigma(a)\subset \{0\}\cup[1,\|a\|]$. In particular, $\|a\|\geq1$  (the case $a=0$ is easily discarded because it forces $b=0$). But $\|a\|\leq\|x\|=1$ (because $a=\frac{x+x^*}2$), so $\|a\|=1$. Now $\sigma(a)\subset\{0,1\}$, so $a$ is a projection. From $a=a^2-b^2$, we get $b^2=0$, so $b=0$. Thus $x=a$ is selfadjoint.

Comment: Took me a minute: $||b||^2=||bb^*||=||b^2||=0$, right.

Comment: That is eactly what I was looking for, thank you very much.

Comment: @David: that's probable neater than the way I think about it. If $b^2=0$, its spectrum is $\{0\}$ and then so is the spectrum of $b$. Being selfadjoint, that's enough.

Comment: @Ugo: glad I could help. I hope you'll stay in the site.