# How do I prove that the given projection is orthogonal?

Tags: hilbert-spaces

Prove that if $H$ is a Hilbert space and $P: H ⟶ H$ is a continuous linear projection of norm one, so $P$ is an orthogonal projection.

I know that the projection thing comes from the fact that $P^2=P$ and that the orthogonality thing comes from the fact that $x-Px⟂M$ where $M$ is a closed subspace of $H$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that if $\|Q\|=1$, then $Q$ is the orthogonal projection of $H$ onto $R(Q)$ (The range of $Q$)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3622683/show-that-if-q-1-then-q-is-the-orthogonal-projection-of-h-onto-rq)

Comment: @Anne Bauval, Do you know where the expression $(∥Q(y)∥^2−∥y∥^2)t^2+2t∥Q(y)∥^2$ comes from in the solution given in the link you mention?

Comment: From developping the inequality obtained just before: $(t+1)^2\|Q(y)\|^2\le\|Q(y)\|^2+t^2\|y\|^2.$